# Will a negative data value have impact on t-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test

I want to test the significant difference between two data sets via t-test.
control group = 2 observations
Treatment group = 2 observations

| Sample | replicate-1 | replicate-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| control | 41.043 | -38.567 |
| treatment | 127.870 | 95.727 |

If I take the control group replicate-2 value (-38.567) as it is, the t-test (parametric as well as nonparametric) shows no significant difference between the control and the treatment group. But, if I neglect the negative sign, then the result shows the significant difference.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Are you performing a t-test with a single observation in each treatment group?

Comment: Please add information about the sample size in each replicate.

Comment: @GeoffreyJohnson both group contains 2 observations. replicate 1 and 2 is the actual observed data of both groups

Comment: @DavidSmithThanks. added number of observations. I just took 2 observations (due to limited sample volume) from each group.

Comment: You probably have insufficient data to make any really useful statistical inference about the system. I do not think that a t-test will be a good way to proceed. However, you may have other relevant information that, along with these data, would help you design a more informative study.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have only two observations in each group.  Although the negative replicate-2 value produces a large estimated effect size, it also produces a large estimate of the population variance (and hence a large estimate for the standard error of the test statistic).  This does not mean there truly is no effect, it just means you do not have a large enough sample size to detect such an effect (if the effect truly exists in the population).

If the replicate-2 value is positive this produces a smaller estimated effect size (compared to the analysis above) but it also produces a smaller estimate of the population variance (and hence a smaller estimate for the standard error of the test statistic).

The correct answer is the one based on the observed data.  If replicate-2 is negative then do not omit the negative sign.  If replicate-2 is positive then do not erroneously apply a negative sign.

I suggest reporting the p-value rather than simply stating the results are "significant" or "not significant."  I also highly recommend reporting a confidence interval.  A 95% Wald confidence interval using the empirical sandwich standard error estimate produces the interval (-8.43, 229.55).  The evidence suggests that the unknown fixed true difference in population means is somewhere within this interval.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. That certainly clears my doubt.